# format not a string literal and no format arguments (not involving NSLog)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nslog

(I am new to objective c so apologies if this seems to be a simple question)

I researched the following message here

format not a string literal and no format arguments

and most of the responses involve an NSLog statement. However, my error shows up with this line

```
NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", [managedObject Name]]];
```

I am troubleshooting a set of code and don't seem to understand why the error is occuring here. any assistance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below should fix it.

```
NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", [managedObject Name]], nil];
```

Alternatively

```
NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", [managedObject Name]];
```

Should also do it.

You were calling two methods that expected a format parameter, you were passing one into the [NSString stringWithFormat] but not the stringByAppendingFormat method.

Answer (score 3):

Beside what the others have said, you should look into

```
- (NSString *)stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString *)aString
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `stringByAppendingFormat`, and then using `stringWithFormat`. Pick one or the other. Fix:

```
NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", [managedObject Name]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", [managedObject Name]
```

will return a string with the `%@` already replaced by the value of `[managedObject Name]`. Therefore, the method `stringByAppendingFormat` is not getting the formatting string and any arguments.

BTW, the convention is to use method names beginning with lowercase alphabets, unlike in `[managedObject Name]`